# Why am I getting a NameError when I pass an argument to a function in python?

Tags: python, function, variables, parameter-passing, nameerror

Here is my python code:

```py
import turtle

def square(t):
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    for i in range(4):
        t.fd(100)
        t.lt(90)

square(bob)
```

When I run my code I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/j/python_projects/tp_ex_4.1.py", line 10, in <module>
    square(bob)
NameError: name 'bob' is not defined
```

I am learning python programming from the book "Think Python How to think like a computer scientist" and I don't understand why my code will not run. I am trying to write a function called `square` that takes a parameter named `t`, which is a `turtle`. I use a for loop to draw a square with the turtle. Then I write a function call that passes `bob` as an argument to square. Shouldn't `bob` replace `t` in my function? Thereby making `bob = turtle.Turtle()`? What am I missing?

Comment: You can pass `bob` as a parameter, but you never defined `bob` previously. However, looking at your code, you don't _need_ to pass a parameter, you define `t` locally as a turtle, so nothing needs to be passed.

Comment: bob is a variable, "bob" is a string so change bob to "bob" square("bob")

Comment: You're passing `bob` _into_ the function. So effectively you're assigning the value of `bob` to `t`. If you need to pass the value of `t` back out into global scope, look into the `return` statement.

Comment: what is ``bob``? What yre you trying to do? Why are you having a ``t`` in your function in the first place if you redefien it in the very first line?

Comment: [This](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) would also be a helpful read. What you're expecting is _pass by reference_ which Python does not support.

Comment: You really must explain what you are *expecting* to happen here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Quite obviously: bob is not defined. It looks like a variable that didn't get any value.

You might have wanted to write to the last line something like this:

```
square('bob')
```

This way 'bob' is a literal and it will work.

Comment: the code will work yes, but "bob" has no sense in this code

Comment: I think with a little closer inspection you would see that you _cannot_ pass a string as a parameter to that function.

Comment: Why will Python pass the literal 'bob' into the function but will not pass the variable bob?

Comment: @J.Hawker **because there is no variable `bob` defined**. That is precisely what a `NameError` is doing. It's no different than `print(banana)`, you will get a `NameError` complaining that `banana` is not defined (unless of course, you have actually defined it somehwere in scope)

Comment: "This way 'bob' is a literal and it will work." it only "works" in the sense that it doesn't throw an error, but this **doesn't do anything useful**

Comment: The chapter I'm in currently is about using the turtle module, defining functions, and using for loops. The point of the assignment was to pass an argument into a function. That is why I'm using 'bob' as the argument. Unfortunately, I didn't understand why my initial code failed because I was trying to use a variable that had not been assigned. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

`bob` is not defined. In this function, you don't even need a parameter since parameters are used to pass values from outer context to the function context, while here you define `t` in the function itself. Change `def square(t):` to `def square():` and `square(bob)` to `square()`